# FIORI custom theme partially overriden by library.css with some users

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, sap-fiori, custom-theme

We have set up a FIORI Launchpad and created a custom theme, which works fine in general.

Now, I realize that
1. only in IE, some CSS-rules from custom.css are overridden by the library.css
2. same with only one user (so far), using an up-to-date chrome version.

I wonder if anyone has experienced similar effects and if there is a known solution. I want the custom.css to be the one in charge.

Custom.css is referred to in all other situations encountered so far.
IE developer tools show the CSS-rules in custom.css struck out.

custom.css
.sapMeCalendarApproval > .sapMeCalendarMonth > div.sapMeCalendarMonthDays > .sapMeCalendarType01.sapMeCalendarMonthDay {
   background-color: green;
}

library.css
.sapMeCalendarApproval > .sapMeCalendarMonth > div.sapMeCalendarMonthDays > .sapMeCalendarType01.sapMeCalendarMonthDay {
   background-color: blue;
}

=> outcome is blue background, green would be expected.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a UI5 bug that will never get fixed as `sap.me.*` controls have been deprecated since many years. Also UI5 dropped support for IE11 recently. Applications should switch to `sap.ui.unified.*` Calendars instead. It is very unlikely that this question adds any values to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use [the "!important" rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), this declaration overrides any other declarations.